# Form Formatting MM/DD/YYYY dates in textbox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

from select_label procedure by HTH

```
Private Sub select_label(msForm_C As MSForms.Control)
    '/* Capture the selected date */
    Dim i As Integer, sel_date As Date
    i = Split(msForm_C.Name, "_")(1) - 1
    sel_date = FirstCalSun(curMonth) + i

    '/* Transfer the date where you want it to go */
    MsgBox sel_date

End Sub
```

I have an UserForm1 that contains TextBox1 with the following code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
SelectDate.Show
End Sub
```

Question is as follows, how can I link my code to TextBox1" with sel_date showing on TextBox1 (UserForm1), TextBox1 has no value and collects sel_date value, this action should be in a loop so I can access to date picker as many times as needed and change the date
appreciate your help

Comment: Your proc `Select_Label` requires the control passed as parameter to have a name of a specific format from which a month can be extracted. Also, your question doesn't make clear whether TextBox1 contains a date which you want to show (in a MsgBox) or whether your intention is to enter a date created by `Select_Label` in TextBox1 when it is clicked. Please modify your question to replace "how can I link my code to TextBox1" with a description of the desired result.